# Android CookieSyncManager calling CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync() in onResume()

Tags: android, webview, onresume, cookiemanager

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this for me as I am a bit confused as to the "why" of it all.  I am using a WebView in my application but I am finding that it is not always correctly syncing my cookies.  I have looked at multiple code examples for the CookieSyncManager and they all say to call CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync(); from within onResume().  My question is, if my application is being resumed why would I want to stop syncing cookies?  Shouldn't I be calling CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync(); in onPause() since my application is losing focus and there won't be anything to sync? Am I just not understanding the way this works properly?

Here is one of the code examples I'm speaking of.  It seems like most other examples I see use the same or similar code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've come to find out that the documentation I posted is correct.  I apparently just have trouble reading. But it seems I'm not alone as other tutorials have made the same mistake because of the way the documentation is laid out.

**To use the CookieSyncManager, the host application has to call the following when the application starts:**

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context)

**To set up for sync, the host application has to call**

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync()

**in Activity.onResume(), and call**

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync()

**in Activity.onPause().**

*Personally, I think it makes more sense to write it this way.*

**To use the CookieSyncManager, the host application has to call the following when the application starts:**

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context)

**To set up for sync, the host application's Activity.onResume() has to call**

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync()

**And then to stop syncing the application's Activity.onPause() has to call**

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync()

Live and learn.